# Make item editor editable of the advancedatagrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid, itemeditor

i have a advance datagrid in which i have 2 columns and every row of the column is a item editor

now i want to edit the row cell on double click i tried various things to make it editable 
some of properties are written in this code.

i make editable property true of colmns Grid and also i tried the rendrerIsEditor to set it true...

```
 <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="varGrid"  width="100%" top="7" bottom="5" left="7" right="7" rowCount="15"
                            sortableColumns="true" editable="true">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" editable="true" dataField="name" sortable="true" editorDataField="text" rendererIsEditor="true">
                    <mx:itemEditor>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemEditor >
                                <s:TextInput id="variableName" text="@{value}" restrict="^\\{\\}" width="100%" height="100%" maxChars="250" 
                                            />
                            </s:GridItemEditor>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemEditor>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>

                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Value" editable="true" dataField="lastValue" sortable="true" rendererIsEditor="true">
                    <mx:itemEditor>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemEditor>
                                <s:TextInput text="@{value}" restrict="^\\{\\}" width="100%" height="100%" maxChars="250"/>
                            </s:GridItemEditor>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemEditor>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns>

            <s:AsyncListView list="{data.variables}"/>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

please help me is i am doing it right or is there something missing in this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

- You want to use a custom `itemEditor`, so don't set `rendererIsEditor="true"`.
- You can't use `s:GridItemEditor` within the `AdvancedDataGrid`. It's for the Spark `s:DataGrid`.
- The `id` attribute is not allowed within `<fx:Component>`.
- Use Spark components as `itemEditor` is not as easy as it used to be with Halo components. I'd recommend you use the `mx:TextInput` instead of the `s:TextInput`. If you need to use the Spark one take a look at [MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/MXAdvancedDataGridItemRenderer.html) and [Using a Spark item renderer with an MX control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-1c32bcb9124deadc3e9-8000.html).

Below is a code snippet that corrects all those issues and uses the `mx:TextInput` component:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="varGrid" width="100%" top="7" bottom="5" left="7" right="7" rowCount="15" sortableColumns="true"
                     editable="true">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" editable="true" dataField="name" sortable="true" editorDataField="text">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:TextInput restrict="^\\{\\}" width="100%" height="100%" maxChars="250"/>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>

        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Value" editable="true" dataField="lastValue" sortable="true">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:TextInput restrict="^\\{\\}" width="100%" height="100%" maxChars="250"/>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>

    <s:AsyncListView list="{data.variables}"/>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```